# How can I query my datastore in google app engine with endpoints to see if two fields contain a string?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gql, google-cloud-endpoints

I have implemented google appengine's endpoints client api libraries into my android application *(Thanks to this tutorial: http://devthots.blogspot.ca/2012/07/building-awesome-android-apps-with.html)*. I am inserting my Entity Object (SOESave) like this:

```
SOESave save = new SOESave();

save.setId(uniqueKey.toString());
save.setName(name);
save.setDesc(desc);
Text jsonText = new Text();
jsonText.setValue(JSON);
save.setJson(jsonText);
save.setDownloadCount(0);
save.setBlobKey(s.toString());

Soesaveendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(endpointBuilder).build();
endpoint.insertSOESave(save).execute();
```

In Soesaveendpoint.java there is this method:

```
public CollectionResponse<SOESave> listSOESave(
        @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
        @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit)
```

If I understand correctly cursorstring will be added onto the end of **"select from SOESave as SOESave"** and used as a query on my datastore, and i can specify the limit here too.

What I cannot figure out is how I can make a query to my datastore that only shows results where the **Title** or **Description** fields contain a specific string.  I couldn't find anything in the [GQL syntax reference](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference) that would help me finding where results contain a string.  Is this even possible with GQL?  Thank you for any responses, and sorry that this post is a little lengthy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core question seems to be: can I query the datastore using something like SQL's `LIKE` statement? The answer to this is no. You can perform comparisons with `>`, `<`, or `=`, but can't do partial matches. For the latter, you'll have to use something like the [Search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/overview).